# Can solving Linear Regression result into zero coefficient of any variable?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, regularization

I was reading about ridge and lasso regularization and I have a question that if solving regression might result in zero coefficient of any variable if it is not useful in prediction at all.

For example, if it is possible that a center of an elliptical region in the below image lies on the axis then it might result in zero coefficient for Ridge Regression. Please correct me if I am wrong. Thank you.[image]

Comment: Upvoted for awesomely cool graphic.

Comment: Ridge regression does not penalize coefficients to zero, LASSO however does and it is one of the fundamental differences between the two.